# Update axis style in transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transition

I'm using syled y axis like in [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3371592) example. I'm changing data dynamically. Axis transition works, but i don't know how to apply the same style for new axis.

Axis before update:

```
var gy = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

var styling = function(selection) {
   selection.selectAll("g").filter(function(d) { return d; })
       .classed("minor", true);
   selection.selectAll("text")
       .attr("x", 4)
       .attr("dy", -4);
};

styling(gy);
```

Axis transition:

```
var update = function() {
   // change data, domain etc
   // ...

   // change axis
   svg.transition()
     .duration(600)
     .select(".y.axis")
     .call(yAxis);

   // how to apply the same style ??
}
```

I've tried in update function something like that, but calling transition on `yAxis` return some different object then before update and got error

> selection.selectAll(...).filter(...).classed is not a function

... so it doesn't work:

```
var gy = svg.transition()
  .duration(600)
  .select(".y.axis")
  .call(yAxis);

styling(gy);
```

Comment: Where are you call `styling` after transition?

Comment: do this in the update `styling(d3.select(".y.axis"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
var gy = svg.transition()
  .duration(600)
  .select(".y.axis")
  .call(yAxis)
```

`gy` is transition object so when you do:

```
styling(gy); //will not work, because styling expects a selection object.
```

so it should have been

```
styling(d3.select(".y.axis")); //inside update function
```